# Comma-separated list output for SQL Server 2012, with many JOINs

Tags: sql-server, join

I have been looking for this answer here in SO, but can't find it.

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel, AA.Agency
FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 
LEFT JOIN Agencies AA ON AA.AgencyID = C.AgencyID
WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1
Order BY RegulatoryModel
```

which generates the following data:

```
RegulatoryModel Agency
DPS-750XB XX    BSMI
DPS-750XB XX    CE Self Declaration
DPS-750XB XX    CQC
DPS-750XB XX    KTC
DPS-750XB XX    Kvalitet
DPS-750XB XX    Nemko
DPS-750XB XX    UL
```

I'm trying to put all the Agencies in one line, like "BSMI, CE Self Declaration, ...", and I've found out how to do that with `stuff` and `FOR XML PATH` (code below), but it's returning EVERY Agency found in the Agencies table, not just the ones associated with this join.  Read about `CROSS APPLY`, but could not figure that one out either.

Not-quite-right code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel,
   AgencyList = stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + A.Agency
    FROM Agencies A
    order by A.Agency
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 
WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1
Order BY RegulatoryModel
```

Suggestions on how to modify the above code to just give a comma-separated list of the Agencies that are matched in this multi-level JOIN?

Comment: already AND RM.Active = 1should be in join otherwise case null will be not take for left outer join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap in CTE first then stuff it.

```
        ;
        WITH    CTE
                  AS ( 


                        SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel, AA.Agency
                        FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
                        LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
                        LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
                        LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 
                        LEFT JOIN Agencies AA ON AA.AgencyID = C.AgencyID
                        WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1
                        Order BY RegulatoryModel


                     )
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                    RM.RegulatoryModel ,
                    AgencyList = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + A.Agency
                                         FROM   CTE A
                                         ORDER BY A.Agency
                                       FOR
                                         XML PATH('')
                                       ), 1, 2, '')
            FROM    CTE RM
```

UPDATED:

```
    ;
    WITH    CTE
              AS ( 


                    SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel, AA.Agency,SBPN.PartNumber
                    FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
                    LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
                    LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
                    LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 
                    LEFT JOIN Agencies AA ON AA.AgencyID = C.AgencyID
                    WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1


                 )
                SELECT DISTINCT
                RM.RegulatoryModel ,
                AgencyList = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + A.Agency
                                     FROM   CTE A
                                     WHERE RM.PartNumber = A.PartNumber
                                     ORDER BY A.Agency
                                   FOR
                                     XML PATH('')
                                   ), 1, 2, '')
        FROM    CTE RM
```

Comment: Had to take the ORDER BY out of the CTE clause, but this got me pretty close!  It worked perfectly if the "source" table (Search_By_PartNumber) only has a single PartNumber in it.  But, if the table has many, the resulting list of Agencies in each seems to be the "superset" of the Agencies from ALL of the rows.

Comment: How about exposing the partner number in the "source table" then in the select stuff cte put a where calause like.. RM.PartNumber = CTE.PartNumber

Comment: That helped a lot!  Between the original answer and the comments, this one was the closest to my solution, so accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this `ON` clause in the original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel, AA.Agency
FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 

LEFT JOIN Agencies AA ON AA.AgencyID = C.AgencyID
                       --^--This one

WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1
Order BY RegulatoryModel
```

And notice how there's no similar condition in your second query? We need to *correlate* your subquery, using this condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RM.RegulatoryModel,
   AgencyList = stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + A.Agency
    FROM Agencies A

    WHERE A.AgencyID = C.AgencyID

    order by A.Agency
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
FROM Search_By_PartNumber SBPN
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels_PartNumbers RMPN ON SBPN.PartNumber = RMPN.PartNumber 
LEFT JOIN RegulatoryModels RM ON RMPN.RegModID = RM.RegModID 
LEFT JOIN Certifications C ON RM.RegModID = C.RegModID 
WHERE RMPN.Active = 1 AND RM.Active = 1
Order BY RegulatoryModel
```

If this isn't giving you the correct output (you still have more rows than you'd like and not enough items are being concatenated), it probably indicates that more of the tables/joins need to move up into the subquery. But bear in mind that you need to make sure that it remains correlated to the outer query.

Note that as Esperento57 mentioned in the comments, the outer `WHERE` clause is slightly suspect (forcing some of the joins to effectively become `INNER` joins).

Also, I'd insert my usual caveats around comma separated data - it's *not* a natural way to represent multiple values in T-SQL. There are types *designed* for holding multiple values (tables, xml, json from 2016 onwards) and CSV strings aren't one of them. Ideally, I'd leave this sort of transformation to a *presentation* layer rather than putting it in the database.

Comment: I tried doing both the simple WHERE in the sub-clause, as well as copying more of the JOINs there as well.  The WHERE didn't have any difference, but I think the JOINs might, if I can get the XML/stuff syntax right.  Getting too many XML angle-brackets in the output right now...

Comment: This output is for a report, so CSV output will give them the data in a more compact format.  User didn't want >100,000 records for some reason...